# ruby/sinatra: will code outside the routes run only once or each time site is pinged?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a slim Sinatra site.

If I include code outside the get routes, will it run in the background only once, or will it trigger each time the IP address is pinged.

For example will the function **'start'** only run once on server creation / gitpush or will it run anew each site visit.

--

```
other-code.rb

$variable
$count = 0
def start
  $variable = "hello world + #{$count}"
  $count += 1
end

start
```

--

```
index.rb

require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'other-code'

get '/' do

content_type :json
    puts $variable

end
```

---

Comment: this doesn't even work... are you running `ruby index.rb` ? I get  `core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- other-code.rb (LoadError)`

Comment: hmm try 'require-relative'

Comment: yeah it was `require_relative` but thanks

Comment: You could run a little test and log a test string to a log file every time `start` is called, our output something to the console every time it's called.

Answer (score 2):

Require only loads the ruby code from the required file once.
Here is how you can tell:

```
#index.rb

require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require_relative 'other_code'

get '/' do
  content_type :json
  puts $variable
end


# other_code.rb

$variable

def start
  $variable = 'hello world'
end
puts 'other code called'
start
```

Now start your sinatra server

```
ruby index.rb
```

You will see this in the console:

```
other code called
== Sinatra (v2.0.5) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Puma
Puma starting in single mode...
```

Then hit your browser a few times and look at your console, you will only see `other code called` output 1 time.  However each time you hit your get route, you should see output `hello world!`